# While using Square checkout API for payment do we need to add transfer fee manually?

Tags: square, square-checkout

I want to use square checkout API for payment integration, I want to know that whether I need to manually add the transaction fee taken by the square in the checkout request generated or it will be added automatically.

Answer (score 0):

With the Checkout API Square will automatically deduct the fees associated to a transaction.

Comment: Ok, so suppose if I want to get paid 10$ after all deductions from square, then I should create a checkout request of 10$ right?